# WPF Validation not firing when first load

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

In Prism application I want to using validation.And I have implement the INotifyDataError interface in my ViewModel ,but I found that the validate solution don't be fired when the control is loaded first time.

Then I found the same Question like '***wpf Validation Binding not fired on First Load***'

I Found a solution to solve the problem **WPF don't fired the validation when first load the datacontext** is that:

```
<TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="textBoxFolder" Margin="2,4">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="this.MovieFolder" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <!--  Validation rule set to run when binding target is updated. -->
                <Rules:MandatoryInputRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

as you see,`ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` is the key point ,this property will make WPF fired the validation when the datacontext load first time.

But I think that's  a ugly solution. I need to add a `Binding.ValidationRules` for every control I want to validate.

Is there a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" try with dis

Answer (score 6):

OK I've solved it: You force the validation when the element got bound with a simple property - ValidatesOnTargetUpdated:

```
 <rules:MyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"  ValidationType="notnull"/>
```